# Logged out of applications intermittently

Tags: siteminder, logoff

I have a siteminder protected portal which has links to many applications that are also protected by siteminder. SSO is implemented between the portal and the applications.

The issue is that when we login to the portal and browse through the applications, it happens sometimes that we suddenly get logged off from the portal for no reason ( no time out, it can happen even for as less as 1 minute).

Issue is reported for a small group of users and it happens on IE as well as Firefox browsers and it happens randomly.

1.Local system time on the policy servers, proxy servers and the user's machine are in sync
2. additionally when I check with Fiddler on the cookies are still there , but we still get logged off from the portal.

Any ideas for this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a persistent session store? This may happen if the validation period is not setup properly.

This may also happen if one of the policy servers has a different encryption key from the others. If you can enabled the trace logs on the web agent, it should give you a decent idea about the reason the cookie is being rejected.